# how do array code work in stairs model?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array, nested-loops

```
int [][] sel = new int [4][];

    int i, j;

    for (i=0; i<sel.length; i++)
        sel [i] = new int [i+1];

    for (i=0; i<sel.length; i++)
        for (j=0; j<sel[i].length; j++)
            sel [i][j] = i+j;

    for (i=0; i<sel.length; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<sel[i].length; j++)
            System.out.print(sel[i][j] + " ");

        System.out.println();
}
```

i was wondering if anyone can helping me and explain to me how this code work (logic). thank's ,, :)

Comment: You'll need to be more specific. What exactly do you not understand? (It would help if you'd format your code more carefully, too.)

Comment: sory, but I wrote it according to example from the book of java, n i do not understand because array output like stairs. first row there are 4 variable, second row 3 variable etc.

Answer (score 0):

Creates an array of arrays (read -> array of pointers to arrays), with size 4

```
int [][] sel = new int [4][];
```

Declare indexes

```
int i, j;
```

Loop over array of pointers and set pointer to an array with length index+1

```
for (i=0; i<sel.length; i++)
    sel [i] = new int [i+1];
```

Set array values **pointer index + array index**

```
//Loop over array of pointers
for (i=0; i<sel.length; i++)
    //Loop over sub array elements
    for (j=0; j<sel[i].length; j++)
        //Set value
        sel [i][j] = i+j;
```

Loop over multidimensional array and print their values separated by space, each array on new line.

```
for (i=0; i<sel.length; i++) {
    for (j=0; j<sel[i].length; j++)
        System.out.print(sel[i][j] + " ");
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Note that in case **for** construct has missing **{scope body}** it will apply only to next line - for beginners this might be confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in Java are Objects, thus each index of multidimensional arrays with unknown or variable lengths must be initialized manually (or just use [Collection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/) and save yourself the headache!) Basically the compiler will generate a portion of code to initialize any array which has an implicit size, as does the base array which is

```
    [4]
```

Subsequent dimensions are "index+1" larger and the compiler has no way of knowing that, hence the first loop which creates them. The second loop populates the created second dimensions, this is actually a terrible example as a proper programmer knows to avoid iterations like the plague; instead he/she should have immediately populated the array in the first loop, like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sel.length; i++) {
    final int size = i+1;
    final int[] dimension = sel[i] = new int[size];
    for(int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        dimension[j] = i+j;
    }
}
```

Several reasons to do this, the primary being a lack of necessity to test the logic or iterate the entire array multiple times for initialization... It is, however, best to distinguish initialization from function, so the second loop to print the values should remain.

Sources:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Answer (score 0):

in 2d array it works like a row and column.

in this line of code you declare an int 2d array variable `sel` with 4 rows and an empty column;

```
int [][] sel = new int [4][];
```

this two variable is used inside the `for loops`

```
int i, j;
```

in this for loop you are assigning an array to the `sel` 's index

```
             // length = 4
for (i=0; i<sel.length; i++)
     //first iteration sel[0] = new int[i+1] 0 + 1 = 1 size of array inside sel[0]
     //second iteration sel[1] = new int[i+1] 1 + 1 = 2 size of array inside sel[1]
     // and so on
    sel [i] = new int [i+1];

     //assigning to the value of `sel` 's column
             // length = 4
for (i=0; i<sel.length; i++)
             // sel[i] or sel[0].length = 1 refer to the first for loop
             //           sel[1].length = 2
    for (j=0; j<sel[i].length; j++)
             //sel[0][0] = 0 + 0;
             //sel[1][0] = 1 + 0;
             // sel[1][1] = 1 + 1;
        sel [i][j] = i+j;

       // displaying the values
            //length = 4
for (i=0; i<sel.length; i++) {
             // sel[i] or sel[0].length = 1 refer to the first for loop
             //           sel[1].length = 2
    for (j=0; j<sel[i].length; j++)
                         //sel[0][0] = 0;
                         //sel[1][0] = 1;
                         //sel[1][1] = 2;
        System.out.print(sel[i][j] + " ");

    System.out.println();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Please find an explanation to the problem.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        /* Java builds multi-dimensional arrays from many one-dimensional arrays, the so-called "arrays of arrays" approach.
         * There are a couple of interesting consequences of this: Rows may be different sizes. 
         * Each row is an object (an array) that can be used independently.  
         * You have initialized an Array with fixed number of rows, and variable number of columns in all the rows.
         * This gives us felxibility to dynamically add 'n' number of columns to each row.
         * if you had declared it say, int[4][4], you could always only add 4 columns to each row.
         * The below example would initialize a  multidimensional array in the below structure.
         *   +-----+    
             |a[0] | -> null
             |     |    
             +-----+
             |     |    
             |a[1] | -> null                        |
             +-----+    
             and so on till a[3]. Note the value for a[n] are empty or null since we have not given the size of the arrays.
             So accessing sel[0][0] would give you null pointer Exception and sel[0] would give you null.
         * 
         */

        int [][] sel = new int [4][];

        int i, j;

        /*
         * Now sel.length would give us the number of rows in the matrix(multi-dimensional array).
         * So all the four arrays(each row) would be initialized with an array by the following for loop. 
         * After the for loop, printing sel[i] would print the hashcode of the array.
         * In this case,
         * 1st row will be an array of size: 1
         * 2nd row: 2
         * 3rd row: 3 and so on. and all the elements will be initialized to zero by default.
         *   +-----+    +-----+
             |a[0] | -> |  0  |
             |     |    +-----+
             +-----+
             |     |    +-----+-----+
             |a[1] | -> |  0  |  0  | 
             +-----+    +-----+-----+

         * 
         */

        for (i=0; i<sel.length; i++)
            sel [i] = new int [i+1];

        /*
         * The below code does nothing but iterates the above created matrix and assigns them a value.
         * sel.length will always be 4.
         * sel[i].length for 1st row will be:1, 2-> 2,3->3, 4->4
         */
        for (i=0; i<sel.length; i++)
            for (j=0; j<sel[i].length; j++)
                sel [i][j] = i+j;

        /*
         * The below code iterates row by row, prints the content of each array in that row and then a new line.
         */
        for (i=0; i<sel.length; i++) {
            for (j=0; j<sel[i].length; j++)
                System.out.print(sel[i][j] + " ");

            System.out.println();
    }
```

Reference: http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/data/arrays/arrays-2D.html